# How to untar a file on s3 directly on s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tar

I have a 10G file .tar file on s3, I want to decompress that file and keep the unzipped files on s3.

Is there a simple command I can run against s3?

Or do I have to unzip the file myself locally, and upload the individual files back to s3 myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no command to manipulate file contents on Amazon S3.

You will need to download the file, untar/unzip it, then upload the content to S3.

This will be done the most quickly from an Amazon EC2 instance in the same region as the bucket. You could potentially write an AWS Lambda function to do this too, but beware of the 500MB `/tmp` disk space limit.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this from the Amazon CLI, or the new [Amazon CloudShell](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/), with a command like

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/data.tar.gz - | tar -xz --to-command='aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/$TAR_REALNAME'
```

Note all those dangling '-' chars are important for piping to stdout/stdin

Comment: what does the hyphen(-) do? What if I had the tar on my local but wanted to extract ti to S3 without saving to windows first?

Comment: @user2441441 I think you should probably ask this as a seperate question. The - characters are used to pipe the output of cp to stdout. You should be able to achieve the same from your local file system by using tar on the left hand side of the pipe | operator with the tar command to output the contents to stdout https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-Standard-Output.html

Comment: I know this is from a while ago but can someone tell me what $TAR_REALNAME represents?

Comment: @JamesFinnegan Name of the file as stored in the archive. https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html

Answer (score 0):

You can, however, mount S3 bucket on EC2 as S3FS.

Here is the link with more detail on how to mount: https://cloudkul.com/blog/mounting-s3-bucket-linux-ec2-instance/

Once mounted you can read and write files to s3 just like you do in local disk.